# Removing a new line feed in json file using Python.

Tags: python, json, pretty-print, linefeed

I am in the process of downloading data from firebase, exporting it into a json. After this I am trying to upload it into bigquery but I need to remove the new line feed for big query to accept it.

```
{   "ConnectionTime": 730669.644775033, 
    "objectId": "eHFvTUNqTR", 
    "CustomName": "Relay Controller", 
    "FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96", 
    "DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561", 
    "PeripheralType": 9, 
    "updatedAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z", 
    "Model": "DF Bluno", 
    "HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7", 
    "Serial": "0123456789", 
    "createdAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z", 
    "Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
{
    "ConnectionTime": 702937.7616419792, 
    "objectId": "uYuT3zgyez", 
    "CustomName": "Relay Controller", 
    "FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96", 
    "DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561", 
    "PeripheralType": 9, 
    "updatedAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", 
    "Model": "DF Bluno", 
    "HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7", 
    "Serial": "0123456789", 
    "createdAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", 
    "Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
```

This is how I need it but can not figure out how to do this besides manually doing it.

```
{"ConnectionTime": 730669.644775033,"objectId": "eHFvTUNqTR","CustomName": "Relay Controller","FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96","DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561","PeripheralType": 9,"updatedAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z","Model": "DF Bluno","HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7","Serial": "0123456789","createdAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z","Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
{"ConnectionTime": 702937.7616419792, "objectId": "uYuT3zgyez", "CustomName": "Relay Controller", "FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96", "DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561", "PeripheralType": 9, "updatedAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", "Model": "DF Bluno", "HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7", "Serial": "0123456789", "createdAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", "Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
```

I am using python to load the json, read it and then write a new one but can not figure out the right code. Thank you!

here is the outline for my python code

```
import json
with open('nospacetest.json', 'r') as f:
  data_json=json.load(f)

#b= the file after code for no line breaks is added

with open('testnoline.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump=(b, outfile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I think the input format might be a single JSON array, and the desired output is newline-separated JSON representations of the elements of that array. If so, this is probably all that's needed:

```
with open('testnoline.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for obj in data_json:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(obj) + "\n")
```

Comment: so know this runs but when i go to open the file it cant open it says there is an unknown error. any suggestions?

Comment: How are you trying to open the file?

Comment: Note that despite the extension `.json`, this will *not* be a valid JSON file. It's a text file with a bunch of JSON objects in it and newlines in between them. So if you're trying to open it in some sort of JSON viewer, that is expected to fail.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to make sure that `indent=None` when you [`dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) you data to json:

```
with open('testnoline.json', 'w') as outfile:   
    json.dump(data_json, outfile, indent=None)
```

Quoting from the doc:

> If `indent` is a non-negative integer, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent level of 0, or negative, will only insert newlines. `None` (the default) selects the most compact representation.

Comment: Thank you so much but this partially worked. now it does not separate the datasets from each other. Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, `indent=None` is the default.

Comment: @smarx of course. it says so explicitly in the doc quoted in the answer.

Comment: Right, I'm just not sure why you included `indent=None` in your code.

Comment: @smarx to draw attention to the effect of this parameter.

Comment: so the 2 data sets I put in are only part of the json file. there are originally thousands of them I just included them so you knew what I wanted it to look like. The indent=None took away all the new lines but now the datasets are not seperated. I need there to be a new line for every dataset but no new lines inside of the dataset. When I export the dataset and view it on the command line there arent any new lines but when I save it to a json it automatically inserts them.

Comment: @W.Stephens It's unclear what the format of the file is. Does it start with `[` and end with `]`? And do the dictionaries have commas between them? (What you shared doesn't.)