# How can I remove spaces and indentations from a JSON file output with Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a Python script to extract data from one JSON file and put it into another:

```
import json

# Step 1: Read the JSON file
with open('input.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Step 2: Extract the specific data    
extracted_data = []

for token in data['tokens']:
    extracted_data.append({
        'symbol': token['symbol'],
        'address': token['address']
    })
    
# Step 3: Write the extracted data to a new JSON file
with open('output.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(extracted_data, file, indent=False)
```

This results in a JSON file formatted like this:

```
    {   
        "symbol": "4INT",
        "address": "0x5CEeBB0947d58Fabde2fc026Ffe4B33ccFE1bA8B"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "AAVE",
        "address": "0xD6DF932A45C0f255f85145f286eA0b292B21C90B"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "ACRE",
        "address": "0x011734f6Ed20E8D011d85Cf7894814B897420acf"
    },
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
    {"symbol": "4INT","address": "0x5CEeBB0947d58Fabde2fc026Ffe4B33ccFE1bA8B"},
    {"symbol": "AAVE","address": "0xD6DF932A45C0f255f85145f286eA0b292B21C90B"},
    {"symbol": "ACRE","address": "0x011734f6Ed20E8D011d85Cf7894814B897420acf"},
```

How can I do this?
I'm very new at coding and got the initial script from ChatGPT.

I tried:

```
json.dump(extracted_data, file, separators=(',', ':'))
```

```
json.dump(extracted_data, file, separators=(',', ':'), indent=None)
```

```
json.dump(extracted_data, file, separators=(',', ':'), indent=0)
```

Comment: Please note that ChatGPT doesn't necessarily produce results that are 100% accurate

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794782/removing-a-new-line-feed-in-json-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your output file as follows:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as o:
    items = ',\n'.join(map(json.dumps, extracted_data))
    o.write(f'[\n{items}\n]')
```

As extracted_data is a list I assume you'll want to wrap the dictionary items in '[' and ']'.

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I wanted!